# Python "return" difficulties

Tags: python, return

First, let me say I have done thorough research trying to understand. But I do not understand the explanations that others have given (which is understood by those who asked the question). This is the code I have problems with:

```
def tax(bill):
    """Adds 8% tax to a restaurant bill."""
    bill *= 1.08
    print "With tax: %f" % bill
    return bill

def tip(bill):
    """Adds 15% tip to a restaurant bill."""
    bill *= 1.15
    print "With tip: %f" % bill
    return bill

meal_cost = 100
meal_with_tax = tax(meal_cost)
meal_with_tip = tip(meal_with_tax)
```

When I delete the first "return bill" and run it, I get the first number but there is an error when it tries to calculate the second number. The def tax(bill) takes 100 and outputs 108 right? So if I delete the first "return bill", then why is def tip(bill) not doing it's calculations with 108 instead of giving an error?

I really have a problem with grasping the most basic concepts of programming. I've been learning intensely for 3 months now and this is where I am. It is a very slippery subject for my mind to grasp and I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: When you delete the return statement a function defaults to returning `None`. This means `meal_with_tax` has the value `None`. What does `None *= 1.15` mean?

Comment: This same question was just closed as a duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33138918/i-dont-understand-return-in-python-and-what-is-a-caller

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why would you use the return statement in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/why-would-you-use-the-return-statement-in-python)

Comment: You just asked this question worded nearly exactly the same way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33138918/i-dont-understand-return-in-python-and-what-is-a-caller.  You need to explain to us why the answers were insufficient, otherwise we can't help you and will just close this question as well.

Comment: Dair: Thank you! Now I understand. I did not know it defaults to returning None. I thought it means it changes the value to 108 and keeps it like that until changed again. 

digitaLink: Yes, but it was not a duplicate because I am seeking a different answer than on the other questions.

Comment: You did add that "I really have a problem with grasping the most basic concepts of programming. I've been learning intensely for 3 months now and this is where I am."  I would advise you find a new teacher.  This is really basic stuff.  If you have a good teacher already, I would advise giving up as you should have learned this by now.

Comment: I find it hard to imagine you have been learning "intensely" for 3 months and still don't understand returns. This is a very basic concept that you should learn in the beginning of any programming course.

Comment: @digitaLink see [Dunning-Kruger effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're misunderstanding the difference between a `return` and `print` statement.

In your `tax(bill)` function, you're multiplying `bill *= 1.08`. You then `print` the value of `bill`. `print` only outputs the value of bill to the console window -- it doesn't store that value or allow it to be used by other functions in any way.

The `return` statement that you're deleting returns the value stored in bill, `108`, to the caller. The caller in this instance is `meal_with_tax = tax(meal_cost)`. This means that the value of `meal_with_tax` is the return value of `tax(bill)`. When you delete `return bill`, you're returning a value of `None`, so the value of `meal_with_tax` is `None`. You want to `return bill` so that you assign the value `108` to `meal_with_tax`.

The reason that `tip(bill)` returns an error is because it's attempting to calculate `None *= 1.15`. The value of `bill` inside `tip(bill)` is not `108` as you think.